# HA Proxy gzip compression with no compression on backend server

Tags: haproxy, http-compression, geddy

I have an HA Proxy server through which requests are routed to the backend. The backend servers are node.js/geddy . Enabling gzip on geddy requires some changes to the core module and I did not want to risk doing that.

My question is if I enable compression in HA Proxy, can it be configured to do the compression/de-compression and send the uncompressed request to the geddy backend and the compressed request back to the client?

```
                   compression/decompression       uncompressed request
                         happens here               no change to code
browser  <=====>          HA Proxy <====>             Node/geddy1
```

On the other hand, if you think that there is an easy way to enable compression on geddy that I'm missing, I'd be happy to implement that. Also, If anyone needs me to discuss my exploration into geddy to figure out what needs to be done to enable compression, I'd be happy to document what I feel were the code changes so that it could be reviewed by somebody else.

Comment: Compression in HAProxy is only applied to responses.  Requests aren't decompressed.  There's no intrinsic reason why compression would be symmetric and the decision to compress a response has no relationship to whether the request was compressed... so I wonder if you are making an assumption that the whole setup is more complicated than it really is... or if you're trying to solve an issue for clients sending compressed requests that your backend can't handle.  Please see if you can clarify this.